# How to create new file and choose its name automatically?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have made the following Bash script (I'm a beginner).

It makes a new directory `programming` and a file in it called `main.cpp`, then opens it in `nano` to let us edit it. Once we save it, it compiles it, changes compiled file's name and executes it. After that it goes back to root directory.

What I want is that everytime this script is executed, a new name is given to the file automatically,  e.g. if executed first time file would be `main.cpp`,
when executed again, it should make a file called `main_1.cpp`, then `main_2.cpp` and so on...

Can i use a `for` loop or `if`-`else` statement?

Here's the script:

```
mkdir programming
cd programming
nano main.cpp
g++ main.cpp
mv a.out main_executable
./main_executable
cd
```

Comment: If you don't care too much about sequential numbers, [`mktemp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/mktemp-invocation.html) might be another solution.

Comment: If you want to have the old versions, you can start with version control using `git`. When you just want the numbering for one long day of code writing, you might set a variable TODAYVERSION and add 1 every time in your script.

Comment: You might want to add some checks (do not make a new version when g++ fails, only start nano when `cd programming` succeeds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  [`mktemp` command](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mktemp) does this, robustly and securely.

Note in particular that it avoids two serious security flaws in your naive implementation -- predictable file names, and symlink attacks.

```
#!/bin/sh
t=$(mktemp -d programmingXXXXXXX) || exit 127
trap 'rm -rf "$t"' HUP INT QUIT TERM  # Clean up if interrupted
cd "$t"
nano main.cpp
g++ main.cpp -o main_executable && ./main_executable
# cd  <- no point in that; the parent shell's cwd will not have been affected
```

You might want to have the script print the name of the generated directory at the end, and/or change it to generate a file instead of a directory.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but basically just test if a main_1.cpp exists, if it does, then find the last (largest) main_# and increment by 1, if it doesn't exist, then just move to main_1.cpp. The following is a code snippet with the basic logic:

```
if [ -e main_1.cpp ]; then
    num=2
    while [ -e "main_${num}.cpp" ]; do
        num=$((num + 1))
    done
    mv main.cpp "main_${num}.cpp"
else
    mv main.cpp main_1.cpp
fi
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `ls` doesn't parse numerically (at least on my machine, with my locale), so, very likely, after the 10th run you'll get into trouble. Moreover, [don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Agreed, however, you won't get into trouble, you will just start the iteration of `while [ -e "main_${num}.cpp" ]` earlier (at `9`).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, to prevent entering the loop earlier, `sort -V` can be added to insure a version sort. The alternative to eliminate `ls` altogether is just to start at `num=1` and loop until all matching files are exhausted.

Comment: You can start looping at `ls main_*.cpp | wc -l`,

Comment: There are prevailing views that parsing the output of `ls` is a no-no due to it's inability to handle special characters, etc.. [** don't parse the output of ls**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)  However, if you can insure you will not encounter any of the pitfalls (on your own box), then those concerns are no longer valid. However, for a public site, and for a general proposition (and without posting a list of disclaimers), it is sound advise. So yes, you can get a count, but to eliminate `ls` completely, looping from `1` is fine. (you can loop thousands without speed penalty)